# Kylo Ren Voice Changer

Tags: distortion, filter, voice-manipulation, timbre, arduino

I'm curious to know what kind of voice changing affects were used on Kylo Ren in Star Wars VII. It sounds like a pretty basic gravelly distortion filter that lowers his voice, but it still sounds unique.

Darth Vader's voice changer had a similar lower-voice/distort affect, but an entirely different timbre.

I'm looking to create my own voice synthesizer with an arduino, so any technical answers are welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I've tried to come close :

I used reaper, Izotope Trash 2 for saturation and Izotope Ozone 5 for multiband compression.
1. pitch shift - 3 semitones
2. Cut some low freqs with EQ
3. Izotope Trash with these settings : https://i.stack.imgur.com/3KlD4.jpg
4. Izotope Ozone with these settings : https://i.stack.imgur.com/zH7Da.jpg

You have to speak very close to the microphone and use a gravely voice.

Comment: Just for clarification, you used Reaper as your DAW, with Izotope FX plugins?

Comment: Yes that's what I used.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. I'll be able to accept the answer when I can get around to trying your solution :)

Comment: Very cool results :)

Answer (score 2):

I have just seen the following article where this sound effect is mentioned (http://www.latimes.com/entertainment/envelope/la-en-craft-star-wars-sound-20160204-story.html).  It is interesting to note that the dialogue was recorded with two mics: one in the helmet itself and the other on the chest.  Clearly the timbre of the two recordings will be different, but there will also be very small time delays (or phase differences) between them. Mixing the two will then produce a comb-filtering effect that will give further timbral changes, depending on the balance between the two signals.  This can then be further enhanced by changing or varying the delay between the two signals by a very small amount (less then 20mS).

It sounds like there is some further processing then to "sweeten" it up.  Saturation/distortion would be a good starting point.